# Количество элементов в строке

Tags: jquery, массивы, for

Нужно немного изменить скрипт. Сейчас количество элементов задается через переменную, в которой статически указывается количество элементов. Как сделать так, чтобы в эту переменную подставлялось автоматически количество элементов из строки?

```js
var offset = [0, 0, 0], max;
$('.row').each(function(i, e) {
    if(!i) {
        $(e).children().each(function(k, o) {
            offset[k] += o.offsetHeight
        })
    } else {
        max = Math.max(...offset);
        $(e).children().each(function(k, o) {
            offset[k] += $(o).css({marginTop: -(max-offset[k])}).height()
        
        })
    }
})
```

```html
<style>
.row div {
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.blue div {
    background-color: #00f;
}
.red div {
    background-color: #f00;
}
.green div {
    background-color: #0f0;
}
</style>

<div class="row blue">
    <div style="height:50px"></div>
    <div style="height:90px"></div>
    <div style="height:30px"></div>
</div>
<div class="row red">
    <div style="height:15px;"></div>
    <div style="height:55px"></div>
    <div style="height:34px"></div>
</div>
<div class="row green">
    <div style="height:80px"></div>
    <div style="height:20px"></div>
    <div style="height:38px"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Количество элементов задается через первую переменную, если там объявить 4-5-6 и более цифр, то скрипт будет работать с таким количеством элементов. Вопрос в том, как в эту переменную подставлять количество элементов из строки, допустим из первой? Количество элементов в каждой строке одинаковое

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var offset = [], max;
$('.row').each(function(i, e) {
    if(!i) {
        $(e).children().each(function(k, o) {
            if (typeof offset[k] == "undefined")
              offset[k] = 0;
            offset[k] += o.offsetHeight
        })
    } else {
        max = Math.max(...offset);
        $(e).children().each(function(k, o) {
            if (typeof offset[k] == "undefined")
              offset[k] = 0;
            offset[k] += $(o).css({marginTop: -(max-offset[k])}).height()
        })
    }
})
```

```html
<style>
.row div {
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.blue div {
    background-color: #00f;
}
.red div {
    background-color: #f00;
}
.green div {
    background-color: #0f0;
}
</style>

<div class="row blue">
    <div style="height:50px"></div>
    <div style="height:90px"></div>
    <div style="height:30px"></div>
</div>
<div class="row red">
    <div style="height:15px;"></div>
    <div style="height:55px"></div>
    <div style="height:34px"></div>
</div>
<div class="row green">
    <div style="height:80px"></div>
    <div style="height:20px"></div>
    <div style="height:38px"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

или

```js
var offset = new Array($('.row:first div').length).fill(0), max;
$('.row').each(function(i, e) {
    if(!i) {
        $(e).children().each(function(k, o) {
            offset[k] += o.offsetHeight
        })
    } else {
        max = Math.max(...offset);
        $(e).children().each(function(k, o) {
            offset[k] += $(o).css({marginTop: -(max-offset[k])}).height()
        })
    }
})
```

```html
<style>
.row div {
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.blue div {
    background-color: #00f;
}
.red div {
    background-color: #f00;
}
.green div {
    background-color: #0f0;
}
</style>

<div class="row blue">
    <div style="height:50px"></div>
    <div style="height:90px"></div>
    <div style="height:30px"></div>
</div>
<div class="row red">
    <div style="height:15px;"></div>
    <div style="height:55px"></div>
    <div style="height:34px"></div>
</div>
<div class="row green">
    <div style="height:80px"></div>
    <div style="height:20px"></div>
    <div style="height:38px"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: @user324358 Пожалуйста. Успехов!